# Nexus 6 no longer turns on, now that I have flashed a Marshmallow ROM + bootloader

Tags: bootloader, 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-6

I have a Google Nexus 6 (Telus/AT&T) and I had been successfully running the Lollipop version of Chroma for months now.

Yesterday I flashed [Chroma Marshmallow ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/development/rom-chroma-01-11-2015-t3000003), and the recommended [Google Apps](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=41020), along with the MRA58K bootloader. Everything went well and I successfully booted into the ROM. After my apps were restored, I rebooted the phone and everything worked just fine.

This morning, I used Titanium Backup to restore my back up of Adblock. After it restored successfully, it prompted me to reboot. Then the phone shut down and I haven't been able to turn the phone on. I am not even able to get into recovery.

Not quite sure what has happened here. The phone rebooted successfully several times since the successful flash. I have had my Nexus 6 charging for quite a while now with the stock USB cable and adapter and still nothing.

When I plug my phone in to my Win10 PC via the USB cable, I get nothing (it would register before).

Is this a sign of flashing the incorrect bootloader? How can I tell what is actually wrong? Is my phone bricked?

I have checked the Chroma thread and even made [an XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/development/rom-chroma-01-11-2015-t3000003/post63741790#post63741790) requesting assistance. But there have been no leads so far.

***Edit to answer @unforgettableid questions;***

> 1. When you charge your phone, does any LED light up?

No, no LED lights up. Mind you, no LEDs would light light up on a stock Nexus 6 anyhow.

> 2. When you hold down your phone's power button for ten or fifteen seconds, what happens? Does the phone vibrate (signalling that it's getting ready to boot up?) Does the screen's backlight turn on? What do you see, hear, and feel?

Absolutely nothing happens. No vibration, no back light. It is like the battery is dead, however it has been charging for well over an hour now using stock cable and adapter (plugged into AC)

***[2015-11-10] Edit to answer additional @unforgettableid questions;***

> Please plug a battery (which is not full) into the phone.
>
> 3. Can the phone successfully charge the battery? Does any voltage travel between the phone and the battery?

Not sure how to plug in a battery to the phone. The battery in the Nexus6 cannot be removed.

> 4. Do you happen to own a clamp ammeter?

I do not.

> 5. Do you happen to have access to a thermal-imaging camera?

No.

> 6. Do you happen to have access to a [JTAG box](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37019/what-is-jtag-in-regards-to-android)?

No.

> 7. Does your phone have [JTAG](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37019/what-is-jtag-in-regards-to-android) pins? 8. How hard are they to access?

Not 100% sure, but it [sounds like](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/help/jtag-interface-nexus-6-t3089190/) you shouldn't need to go that route with a Nexus 6.

> 9. Please boot up Linux. Enter `lsusb`. What do you see? Enter `dmesg`. What do you see?

**lsusb** output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2001:3314 D-Link Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**dmesg** output:

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/wAuLxMXU)

> you may also start a dedicated thread

[XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/help/nexus-6-longer-flashed-marshmallow-rom-t3246145)

I also tried [this approach](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/general/fix-fix-qhusbbulk-cm12-t3059518) but even after installing all of the drivers, I do not get a response when the Nexus is plugged into the PC, and thus can't rescue it.

Comment: Did you check device manager for something like "Qualcomm_QHUSB" or "Qualcomm_QDLOADER" or something etcetera? You might still be able to enable a sort of UART/JTAG and recover your device.

Comment: @Tamoghna Chowdhury - still nothing shows up when I plug in the Nexus into the PC. However when I plug in my wife's working Nexus 6, I do see the device in the device manager

Comment: 9. Please boot up Linux. You don't have to install it: you can use a live CD. Choose any Linux distribution you like. Ubuntu is a fine choice. Attach your phone to your PC. Open up `xterm` or any other terminal emulator. Enter `lsusb`. What do you see? Enter `dmesg`. What do you see?

Comment: If you like, you may also start a dedicated thread for your problem at http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/help and provide us with a link to it. If you post in your ROM's XDA megathread, your posts can get lost in the sea of conversation.

Comment: My mistake regarding the battery.  I mistakenly assumed that your phone's battery was removable.

Comment: Did you try in another pc ? A Windows 7 may be. Even battery may be dead