# Installing bootloader on completely wiped phone

Tags: bootloader

My phone had an issue where it wouldn't leave the boot screen, so I reinstalled the bootloader and it didn't do anything. Then I formated the ENTIRE phone, including the repair menu, and now I have no tool that allows me to edit my phone.

What I need you to tell/teach me is how to install a bootloader here now, with what tool, and where do I get the files. My phone is a One Touch Star 6010X, and now is competely clean in memory.

Comment: If you've really wiped the bootloader and there is no backup bootchain, there's absolutely nothing you can do unless you have a jig/JTAG to write directly to the hardware or something similar.  It's a "hard brick".  How did you wipe it?

Comment: @MatthewRead what is a jig/JTAG ? I wiped it using the Smart Phone Flash Tool.

Comment: @RaKXeR See [What is JTAG in regards to Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/37019)

Comment: A jig is usually a simple USB connector that will force the device into a firmware download mode, and JTAG is a connector that can write directly to the chips.  So you checked off every partition in SP Flash Tool and blew it all away?  It looks like Mediatek devices might have their own JTAG-esque communication channel over USB, you could try this: http://devs-lab.com/2015/05/how-to-unbrick-mediatek-device.html

Comment: @MatthewRead I cant do anything on my phone with that program now, because when I try to use it the connection fails, giving me the error 5054 (Obtain DRAM Failed) (BROM ERROR: S_DL_GET_DRAM_SETTING_FAIL)

Comment: I see lots of results on Google for ROMs for this.  Most promising one: http://firmwares2you.blogspot.ca/2015/05/alcatel-one-touch-star-6010x.html (note that on the download page it links, the big blue button is the legitimate download link).  Did you install the VCOM drivers?

Comment: @MatthewRead the one you just found is actually the one I tried. by the looks of things, the issue is it doesn't come with the preloader file, which seems to be a must (probably the only reason it worked before is because the file was already on my phone, which isn't the case anymore since I nuked it). thanks for helping me out btw. searching for the file now, might take a while

Comment: @MatthewRead it worked.... it *** worked!!! I didn't actually have to download the file, it was already there, but I had to manually find it, instead of having it find it by itself. I will make an actual answer tomorow but I'm too hyped to do it. thank you for the help again ^w^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue here was that I did not have all files selected in SPFT when "downloading" (actually uploading) the files onto my device.

So, if you follow the steps [here](http://firmwares2you.blogspot.pt/2015/05/alcatel-one-touch-star-6010x.html) on a fully wiped phone, you need to get the ROM for your phone (the set of files that represent pretty much your future Operating System), select the .txt file to automatically find most files, and the manually search for the ones that can't be located by the program.

Comment: I recommend you to edit the answer by including the info provided by the link. This is because we may need to access such info in the future, and we have no assurance that the linked website won't be down when we'll need it.