# Galaxy What does 'Secure JTAG Disabled' mean?

Tags: samsung, unbricking

On my galaxy, when I enter Download Mode it says the following

ODIN MODE  (in red)
Download Speed: Fast (in red)
Product Name: SM-G925F (in white)
System Status: Official (in white)
FRP Lock: On (in white)
Secure Download (in blue)
Warranty Void: 0 (0×0000)
AP SWREV: B:2 K:0 S:0
Secure JTAG DISABLED!!!

What does it mean

My sisters other phone(same model) is hard bricked. Does 'secure JTAG DISABLED' mean that it doesn't support JTAG debugging?

Answer (score 1):

> Does 'secure JTAG DISABLED' mean that it doesn't support JTAG debugging?

**Yes**

[Secure JTAG](http://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001945-13/concept/trustfence/c_secure_jtag_android.htm) explains

> **Disabled JTAG:** This mode provides maximum security. All security-sensitive JTAG features are permanently blocked, preventing any debug.....

Related [What is JTAG in regards to Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37019/131553)

Comment: I do wonder how many still uses JTAG nowadays... It's already a tedious job to tear the phone down to where you can see the contact at all.

Comment: @AndyYan: Don't know currently but when Note 2 was popular, I saw in big repair shops this kit in India